# Windows 10 update failure with MS Office 2010 issue

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, .net-framework, microsoft-office-2010

I have a Windows 10 upgrade that is behaving abnormally when it does automatic updates.  This is also causing me an issue with installing Office 2010.

I have several automatic updates that are downloading and installing correctly.  However, 3 fail without giving any details that I can use to determine the issue.  I have downloaded them directly from the catalog and they try to install, but fail without an error message.  The updates are KB3103688, KB3106932, and KB3105213.

What I think is related is my installation of Microsoft Office 2010.  When the installer runs, it gets so far and then gives me the following error

`"Error 1935: An error occurred during the installation of assembly component {A75F2217-AD54-3EA6-AE14-F255F8660531} HRESULT: 0x80071A91".  After rollback, this is followed by a "Fatal error during installation."`

I also get an intermittent error regarding installation of the 2.5 and 3.5 frameworks, of which I do not have the text at this moment.  I have tried to install the frameworks, as well as the 4.0 and 4.5, but it tells me they are already installed.  However, I cannot see them in my installed applications - I can only see 1.1.

I am running Windows 10 Pro on an i3, and I have nearly a TB free on the hard drive.  64 bit.

Comment: Provide those specific error messages

Comment: @Ramhound he already posed the error. I highlighted it for you ;)

Comment: have you tried my steps? Do the updates now work fine?

Answer (score 0):

You get the error `0x80071A91` which means `ERROR_RM_NOT_ACTIVE`. Open Explorer, delete all files from `C:\Windows\System32\config\TxR` (make sure  hidden files are shown in Explorer), now open a [cmd.exe as Admin](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token) and run this command:

```
fsutil resource setautoreset true C:\
```

Now reboot Windows and after the reboot, try to install Office 2010 again.